# Wireless charger reverse engineering

Tags: h-bridge, usb-device, charge-pump, wireless-charging, p-channel

I am trying to figure out how to design an H-bridge for a wireless charger. And I thought that reverse engineering an off-the-shelf one might give me some clues.

I might have made numerous mistakes reverse engineering it. Or it's just the chinesium 2 dollar circuitry.

But it only constituted some more questions:

1. I was expecting a second charge pump(?), I assume that the thing attached to pins 14 and 15 is a singular charge pump. And I was expecting one charge pump per P-channel MOSFET.
2. I have triple checked the polarity of D3 (below R14, sorry for handwriting) and it makes no sense to me. Doesn't it block the charge pump from interacting with the P-channels?
3. And finally why are the gates of P-channel MOSFETs are effectively shorted to their drains?

Also I expected some sort of frequency sensing, because the charger is not continuously on when idling. So I have no idea how the IC can sense a coupled receiver and transmit power continuously.

A bonus question, I am fairly sure I didn't mess this one up, because the linear regulator clearly states HT50. What's the point of regulating USB Vbus down to 5 volts? xD It's not even USB C, just good old micro USB. And what's the point of connection noted E? I don't think it is able to communicate with the host.

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is no question in `1.`

Comment: Why would the PMOS transistors need a charge pump at all? Normally, that's only required when using NMOS as the high-side switches. The circuit on pins 14 and 15 looks more like some kind of envelope detector, especially given that it is capacitively coupled to the pins.